# Build basic Adobe Kuler-type construction: improving performance / speed

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, image-processing, color

[Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/create/image/) is a useful web tool to create colour palettes, but it is limited to 5 colours. I am trying to make a basic Kuler-type construction, but it is very slow, and crashes on my computer  for > 4 colours. My effort so far handles a reasonable number of colours for just 1 colour scheme:

```
    kul[img_] :=

  Module[{nn, aa, im, col, pos, ff, gg}, 

    nn = 9; aa = 400;
    im = ImageResize[img, aa];
    col = (First@Nearest[Flatten[ImageData[im], 1], #] & /@ 
      DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[
      DeleteDuplicates /@ ImageData[ColorQuantize[img, nn]]], 1], 
      Chop[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] == 0 && Chop[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] == 0 && 
      Chop[#1[[3]] - #2[[3]]] == 0 &]);
    pos = {#[[2]], ImageDimensions[im][[2]] + 1 - #[[1]]} & /@   
      (RandomChoice[Position[ImageData[im], #], 1][[1]] & /@ col);
    ff[a_, im_] := Quiet@{{ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]][[a]], 
      pos[[a]]}, Locator, Appearance -> Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, .11], 
      RGBColor[ImageValue[im, ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]][[a]]]],
      Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> aa/10]};

        Manipulate[Row@{Show[im, ImageSize -> aa], 
          Show[ArrayPlot[Partition[{
            RGBColor[ImageValue[im, a]], 
            RGBColor[ImageValue[im, b]], RGBColor[ImageValue[im, c]], 
            RGBColor[ImageValue[im, d]], RGBColor[ImageValue[im, e]], 
            RGBColor[ImageValue[im, f]], RGBColor[ImageValue[im, g]], 
            RGBColor[ImageValue[im, h]], RGBColor[ImageValue[im, i]]}, 
          3]], ImageSize -> aa/2]},

          Evaluate@ff[1, im], Evaluate@ff[2, im], Evaluate@ff[3, im], 
          Evaluate@ff[4, im], Evaluate@ff[5, im], Evaluate@ff[6, im], 
          Evaluate@ff[7, im], Evaluate@ff[8, im], Evaluate@ff[9, im]]]

kul[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]
```

but when I try to find more colour-schemes, everything becomes very slow, and and crashes for > 4 colours:

```
nn = 4; aa = 400; im = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], aa];
findc[collist_] := (RandomChoice[Nearest[Flatten[ImageData[im], 1], #], 
    1][[1]] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[collist, Chop[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] == 0 && 
    Chop[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] == 0 && Chop[#1[[3]] - #2[[3]]] == 0 &]);
gg[c_, d_] := Blend[{White, c, Black}, Interpolation[Transpose[{{1, 
    First[ColorConvert[Blend[{White, c, Black}, 0.5], "Grayscale"]], 0}, 
    {0, 0.5, 1}}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][d]];
hh[c_, k_] := If[k == 1, gg[c, .75], If[k == 2, gg[c, .25], c]];
ff[im_, c_, k_] := Quiet@{{c, pos[[Position[ToExpression[
    CharacterRange["a", "z"]], c][[1, 1]]]]}, Locator, Appearance -> 
    Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, .11], hh[RGBColor[ImageValue[im, c]], k], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> aa/10]};
ii[im_, c_, k_] := hh[RGBColor[ImageValue[im, c]], k];
jj[li_] := {#[[2]], ImageDimensions[im][[2]] + 1 - #[[1]]} & /@ 
    (RandomChoice[Position[ImageData[im], #], 1][[1]] & /@ li);

col = findc[Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[DeleteDuplicates /@   
    ImageData[ColorQuantize[im, nn]]], 1]];
col1 = RandomChoice /@ Nearest[Flatten[ImageData[im], 1],
    (List @@@ (hh[RGBColor@#, 1] & /@ col))];
col2 = RandomChoice /@ Nearest[Flatten[ImageData[im], 1], 
    (List @@@ (hh[RGBColor@#, 2] & /@ col))];
pos = jj@col; pos1 = jj@col1; pos2 = jj@col2;

Manipulate[
    a = If[k == 0, pos[[#]], If[k == 1, pos1[[#]], pos2[[#]]]] &@1; 
    b = If[k == 0, pos[[#]], If[k == 1, pos1[[#]], pos2[[#]]]] &@2;
    c = If[k == 0, pos[[#]], If[k == 1, pos1[[#]], pos2[[#]]]] &@3; 
    d = If[k == 0, pos[[#]], If[k == 1, pos1[[#]], pos2[[#]]]] &@4; 
        Row@{Show[im, ImageSize -> aa], 
        Show[ArrayPlot[Partition[{ii[im, a, k], ii[im, b, k], 
            ii[im, c, k], ii[im, d, k]}, 2]], ImageSize -> aa/2]}, 
        Evaluate@ff[im, a, k], Evaluate@ff[im, b, k], 
        Evaluate@ff[im, c, k], Evaluate@ff[im, d, k], {{k, 0}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, with no explanations too. Would you please isolate the slowest part yourself and present only that for our consideration in a minimal working example?